# Get Google OAuth credentials using Python

Tags: python, google-oauth

Trying to get Get Google OAuth credentials, as mentioned in this [sample](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant):

```
google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets c:\temp\client_secret_NNNN.json \
                 --credentials c:\temp\credentials.json \
                 --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \
                 --save
```

But calling this command there is no `credentials.json` file created. Any suggestions?

**client_secret_NNNN.json:**

```
{
    "installed": {
        "client_id": "NNNN.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "personal-stuff-54a54",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
            "http://localhost"
        ]
    }
}
```

Log:

```
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=633452378895-dg56psuf7er87nh1ehmoluekkkv0qj0j.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fassistant-sdk-prototype&state=6vqzd8wqETrkbsAwSVbvlrFKcJ4Vs8&access_type=offline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\konopko\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\konopko\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\konopko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\google-oauthlib-tool.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\konopko\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\konopko\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\konopko\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\konopko\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\konopko\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\tool\__main__.py", line 104, in main
    creds = flow.run_local_server()
  File "c:\users\konopko\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 420, in run_local_server
    self.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
  File "c:\users\konopko\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 239, in fetch_token
    kwargs.setdefault('client_secret', self.client_config['client_secret'])
KeyError: 'client_secret'
```

Comment: Do you mean that it is not generated at all, or not generated in your app project directory? Your command directs it to `c:\temp`, not to your app bundle.

Comment: @JereKäpyaho I expecting file going to be created in `c:\temp` but there is nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `client_secret_NNNN.json` should have a key `client_secret`, which is missing in your example. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials. You see a list of your OAuth2 client IDs. On the very right side of each client ID, there is a pen icon. Click it. On the page which now opens, you will see Client ID, Client secret, and Creation date. The Client secret should go into `client_secret`. The page also offers a download of the client secrets file, which then looks like this:

```
{
    "installed": {
        "client_id": "your-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "your-project-id",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "your-very-secret-token-here",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
            "http://localhost"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't find Client secret field in page you mentioned, can see only Client ID ans Creation date. Donwloaded file not contains Client secret too.

Comment: Got Client secret in web ID, then download json. But trying to get credentials I've got `redirect_uri_mismatch` error. Request details: `response_type=code
client_id=NNNN.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype
state=dgEOR2ppQuoe8Qo6Z2UW3njf6K1j0S
access_type=offline`. Google says: The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

Comment: This is strange. Could you tell more what is happening on your computer? I would expect the browser to be opened. Is there an error there (such es HTTP 40x or 500)?

Comment: I've just created new OAuth 2 key with type Other and this works great for now! Thanks Adrian